# Parsing Human Names and matching them in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, names

I'm looking for a gem or project that would let me identify that two names are the same person.  For example

> `J.R. Smith == John R. Smith == John Smith == John Roy Smith == Johnny Smith`

I think you get the idea.  I know nothing is going to be 100% accurate but I'd like to get something that at least handles the majority of cases.  I know that last one is probably going to need a database of nicknames.

Comment: How do you know that these are the same person?

Comment: Humans who want to be identified will use a pretty consistent spelling of their name. The ones who don't want to be identified will be wildly different and no algorithm will catch it using only a name string. You'd have to also match addresses, phone numbers, zip-codes, credit-card numbers, email addresses, or whatever else you have that can uniquely identify them. Also, consider that "J." could be "John", "James", "Jerry", or any alternate spelling, like "Jon".

Comment: I don't know 100% they are the same but I'm doing this in a context of Company Executives so for the most part I think I can be relatively sure they are the same person.  Generally there is only one variation in the names I see and I have other ways of deduping.  I just need to know from a human perspective if the names conceivably match.

Comment: Don't use the names as identifiers. Use another field; like social security numbers, or even database ids.

Comment: I don't have anything other then the name and positions but the positions seem to also vary a bit.

Comment: Try this bro: [https://github.com/mericson/people](https://github.com/mericson/people) . It can help.

Comment: Found this when trying to address this same problem: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names It shows how difficult is to find rules to parse names. Nonetheless, there are some attempts to do it. Google "name parsing gem" to find a couple. mjnissim points to one here. @inukshuk's answer is another. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think one option would be to use a ruby implementation of the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

The Levenshtein distance between two strings is defined as the minimum number of edits needed to transform one string into the other, with the allowable edit operations being insertion, deletion, or substitution of a single character.

Then you could define that names with a distance less than X (being X a number you will have to tweak) are from the same person.

**EDIT**
Through a little search I was able to find another algorithm, based on phonetics called [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone)

Still has a lot of holes in it, but I think that in this case the best everyone can do is to give you alternatives for you to test and see what works best

Comment: I disagree that the Levenshtein distance is the best way to model this. "Athanasios Theodorou" is likely the same person as "Tom Theodorou", whereas "K. Smith" is definitely not the same person as "M. Smith". Unfortunately, I have to give you -1 for this answer.

Comment: I agree with you, but it's a way of getting at least some results right. This is a very complex process, not to say impossible.

Comment: Then you should mention that in your answer and remove the bit about it being the "best **and only** option", in which case I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Based on @hadees comment " I am bringing data in from multiple sources about companies and the executive names sometimes vary a bit", I think using Levenshtein distance, might work since the task is narrowed down a lot based on the company.

Comment: Like I said in my edit, the best we can do is to give suggestions of methods that can help. There isn't going to be any "out of the box" solution.

Comment: There is definitely room for a Ruby name-matching project that is not simply Levenshtein distance (think data mining, online wedding RSVP, etc.), but at a minimum you can do an exact match on surname plus Levenshtein on everything that precedes it.  Be prepared for sometimes odd results.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little late (and a shameless plug to boot), but for what it's worth, I wrote a [human name parser](https://rubygems.org/gems/namae) during a GSoC project, which you can install with `gem install namae`. It does not detect your duplicates reliably obviously, but it helps you with such kind of tasks.

For instance, you can parse the names in your example and use a display form using initials to detect names whose initials are identical, and so on and so forth:

```
names = Namae.parse('J.R. Smith and John R. Smith and John Smith and John Roy Smith and Johnny Smith ')
names.map { |n| [n.given, n.family] }
#=> => [["J.R.", "Smith"], ["John R.", "Smith"], ["John", "Smith"], ["John Roy", "Smith"], ["Johnny", "Smith"]]
names.map { |n| n.initials expand: true }
#=> ["J.R. Smith", "J.R. Smith", "J. Smith", "J.R. Smith", "J. Smith"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

1: Convert names to arrays:

```
irb> names.map!{|n|n.scan(/[^\s.]+\.?/)}
["J.", "R.", "Smith"]
["John", "R.", "Smith"]
["John", "Smith"]
["John", "Roy", "Smith"]
["Johnny", "Smith"]
```

2: Some function of identity:

```
for a,b in names.combination(2)
    p [(a&b).size,a,b]
end
[2, ["J.", "R.", "Smith"], ["John", "R.", "Smith"]]
[1, ["J.", "R.", "Smith"], ["John", "Smith"]]
[1, ["J.", "R.", "Smith"], ["John", "Roy", "Smith"]]
[1, ["J.", "R.", "Smith"], ["Johnny", "Smith"]]
[2, ["John", "R.", "Smith"], ["John", "Smith"]]
[2, ["John", "R.", "Smith"], ["John", "Roy", "Smith"]]
[1, ["John", "R.", "Smith"], ["Johnny", "Smith"]]
[2, ["John", "Smith"], ["John", "Roy", "Smith"]]
[1, ["John", "Smith"], ["Johnny", "Smith"]]
[1, ["John", "Roy", "Smith"], ["Johnny", "Smith"]]
```

Or instead of `&` you may use `.permutation` + `.zip` + `.max` to apply some custom function, which determines, are to parts of names identical.

---

UPD:

```
aim = 'Rob Bobbie Johnson'
candidates = [
    "Bob Robbie John",
    "Bobbie J. Roberto",
    "R.J.B.",
]

$synonyms = Hash[ [
    ["bob",["bobbie"]],
    ["rob",["robbie","roberto"]],
] ]

def prepare name
    name.scan(/[^\s.]+\.?/).map &:downcase
end

def mf a,b # magick function
    a.zip(b).map do |i,j|
        next 1 if i == j
        next 0.9 if $synonyms[i].to_a.include?(j) || $synonyms[j].to_a.include?(i)
        next 0.5 if i[/\.$/] && j.start_with?(i.chomp '.')
        next 0.5 if j[/\.$/] && i.start_with?(j.chomp '.')
        -10 # if some part of name appears to be different -
            # it's bad even if another two parts were good
    end.inject :+
end

for c in candidates
    results = prepare(c).permutation.map do |per|
        [mf(prepare(aim),per),per]
    end
    p [results.transpose.first.max,c]
end
```

---

```
[-8.2, "Bob Robbie John"]  # 0.9 + 0.9 - 10 # Johnson != John # I think ..)
[2.4, "Bobbie J. Roberto"] # 1 + 0.9 + 0.5 # Rob == Roberto, Bobbie == Bobbie, Johnson ~~ J.
[1.5, "R.J.B."]            # 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5
```

Comment: the strings should be folded to lowercase to increase the target size, then mapped back to the original name-case after matching.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who has to try to match human names from different data sources, this is a VERY hard problem to address. Using a *combination* of 3 gems seems to do pretty well.

We have an application where we have a million people in List A, and need to match them with dozens of different data sources. (And despite what some of the more pedantic comments claim, that is not a 'design flaw' that is the nature of dealing with 'real world' messy data.)

The only thing we have found to work reasonably well thus far is  using a combination of the `namae` gem (for parsing names into a standardize first, middle, last, suffix representation) and the `text` gem to calculate levenshtein, soundex, metaphone, and porter scores, AND also `fuzzy-string-match` which calculates the JaroWinkler score (which is often the best of the lot).

1. parse into a standard format separating last, first, middle, suffix using namae. We pre-process with a regex to extract nicknames when formatted `John "JJ" Doe` or `Samuel (Sammy) Smith`
2. calculate ALL scores on a sanitized version of the full name (all caps, remove punctuation, last name first) ... jarowinkler, soundex, levenshtein, metaphone, white, porter. (JaroWinkler and Soundex often do the best.)
3. declare a match if N scores exceed individually set thresholds. (We use any 2 that pass as a pass)
4. if no match, try again using only last name, first name, middle **initial**, with higher thresholds (eg, stricter matching).
5. Still no match, replace first name with nick name (if any) and try again.

With some tweaking of score thresholds for each scoring method, we get pretty good results. YMMV.

BTW putting last name first is very important, at least for JaroWinkler since there is generally less variation in last names (Smithe is almost always Smithe, but first name might be Tom or Tommy or Thomas in different data sources), and the beginning of the string is most 'sensitive' in JaroWinkler. For a "ROB SMITHE / ROBIN SMITHE, the JaroWinkler distance is 0.91 if you do first name first, but 0.99 if you do last name first.

Comment: I believe fuzzy-string-match is redundant as the DidYouMean gem (which I believe is part of the Ruby standard library post Ruby 2.3) contains an implementation of JaroWinkler: https://github.com/yuki24/did_you_mean/blob/3e506439359112757d3790a5d5f498384ec7db77/lib/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb#L62

Answer (score 1):

The best pre-coded you will probably find for this is the gem just called "text".

```
https://github.com/threedaymonk/text
```

It has a number of matching algorithms: Levenshtein Distance, Metaphone, Soundex, and more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a library exists.

I don't mean to offend, but this problem seems like it arises from poor design. Maybe if you post more details about the general problem you are trying to solve, people can suggest a better way.

Comment: It isn't a design problem.  I am bringing data in from multiple sources about companies and the executive names sometimes vary a bit.

Comment: @hadees : In that case, you have a tough problem on your hands. You will probably just have to think about it for a while and code your own function to do it.

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured that but I was hoping someone might have already done it.  I found a database that has nicknames so that should help.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a very nice gem called `text` and I've found the `Text::WhiteSimilarity` to be very good myself but it also implements a bunch of other tests

Answer (score 0):

One initial attempt at a robust human name matcher / clustering solution in Ruby: https://github.com/adrianomitre/match_author_names