# Ruby regex: remove first name, leave last name

Tags: ruby, regex

I am parsing a text and I want to ignore people's first names.

Examples (cases):

- B.Obama => Obama
- B. Obama => Obama
- B . Obama => Obama

I manage to write this working Ruby regex:

```
"B.Obama".gsub(/\p{L}+\.(\p{L}+)/, '\\1')
```

However, it solves only one case. Also, it doesn't check, if the first letter is capital.

So, how should the regex, which combines all these cases, look like?

Details: Ruby 1.92 and UTF-8 strings.

Comment: There is *no way* to parse names, not with regex, not with any other tool. Names are just too variable for this. Compare `Christoph Willibald Gluck` and `Federico García Lorca`. How would you know that `Willibald` is a given name, and `García` is part of the last name?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731730/parsing-human-names-and-matching-them-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Gave a it a little bit more thought and I like this better:

```
/^(\w+)[ .,](.+$)/
```

This will capture both the first name and last name in different capturing groups
i.e.

```
"Mark del cato".scan /^(\w+)[ .,](.+$)/
```

see rubular for example: [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/ftVWXjyGhn)

Or Try

```
^[^ .]+
```

This will pick up the first word on a line. that is not delimited by a dot or a space.
Hope it helps, see example at [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/px8MNE26wd)

Comment: Why have you accepted this answer, which captures the first word unnecessarily, instead of the answer by @ElRonnoco that is simpler and captures only the last name?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(\w+)$
```

`\w+` matches one or more 'word' characters.

The `$` is a zero-length match matching the end of the string.

Do you want to be able to pull second names from a piece of text? That could get very difficult. Can you post an excerpt of your text?

Comment: And what if the last name was something like "del Cacto"?

Comment: What if their full name was Mark Del Cacto? (Del being an abbreviation of Derek). Regular expressions aren't a foolproof way of finding out peoples' last names! :)